# 2nd FTOC, Splitting the Integral

Tags: calculus

I am working on an old GRE exam and ran across a problem;

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x^3}^{x^4}e^{t^2}dt=$$

By the 2nd FTOC, I know that for an element $a$ in the interval of integration, and as long as $f$ is continuous on that interval, then

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)dt=f(x)$$

We have different bounds though. My thought was this. Choose an $a<x^4, a<x^3$.  Then we can break the integral up into

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x^4}e^{t^2}dt-\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x^3}e^{t^2}dt=$$

From here I can use the chain rule to get the indiviual integrals, but I was curious if splitting the integral is correct?

Comment: the derivative is just $$\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \left(\frac{8 e^{x^8} x^3}{\sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{6 e^{x^6}
   x^2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)$$

Comment: So I was correct it appears?  Curious why you bothered not to simplify? My answer was  $e^{x^6}x^2(4xe^{x^8-x^6}-3)$

Comment: i left the simplification for you!

Comment: So i was correct in my splitting the integral.  That was my question.  Thank you!

Comment: @AveryJessup Why did you split it up to begin with though? I'm also not sure if this is technically correct, but I would've done this: $f(t) = e^{t^2}$, $F(t) = \int f(t) dt$. Then your problem reduces to $\dfrac {d}{dx}\left[ F(x^4) - F(x^3) \right ] = 4x^3F'(x^4) - 3x^2 F'(x^3)$.

Comment: Ah, so you can use both FTOC's.  That seems much cleaner.

Comment: You are correct in splitting the integral as you did. This allows you to solve it by using the first FTOC only. No need to invoke second FTOC which is needed only when evaluating the integral.

Comment: Also note that the use of second FTOC is allowed only when the integrand possesses an anti-derivative. Thus it may fail in case the integrand is discontinuous. The splitting of integral combined with first FTOC always works